# XSLT - XSL stylesheet not applying Ive tried everything

Tags: xml, xslt

Just wondering if anyone can help me or point me in the right direction as I just cant get this thing to work, so when I put in the link etc for the XSL stylesheet it just displays whats in the XML like its not linked, I have changed the settings on my IE so it now does look at the stylesheet as before there was a security issue I changed it so it loads in IE not edge.

This is a snippet of my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="TransformDocument.xsl"?>
<root>
  <listing>
    <seller_info>
      <seller_name>jenzen12 </seller_name>
      <seller_rating>new </seller_rating>
    </seller_info>
    <payment_types>
    Accepts Credit Cards (MC, VISA)
    </payment_types>
    <shipping_info>
      * Buyer Pays Shipping
      * Seller Ships on Payment
    </shipping_info>
    <buyer_protection_info>
      Standard Protection Coverage
    </buyer_protection_info>
    <auction_info>
      <current_bid>$310.00 </current_bid>
      <time_left>4 days </time_left>
      <high_bidder>
        <bidder_name>mike_and_colleen </bidder_name>
        <bidder_rating>1 </bidder_rating>
      </high_bidder>
      <num_items>5 </num_items>
      <num_bids>27  </num_bids>
      <started_at>$10.00 </started_at>
      <bid_increment>$5.00 </bid_increment>
      <location>Costa Meca, CA </location>
      <opened>Nov 27 00:24 PST </opened>
      <closed>Dec 02 10:24 PST </closed>
      <id_num>45519743 </id_num>
```

And this is the XSL document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3org1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <head>
    <link href="CSSStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/listing"/>
        <xsl:sort select="seller_info_seller_name" order="ascending/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </body>
</html>
    <xsl:template match="listing">  
    <div class="seller">
    <xsl:value-of select="seller_info/seller_name"/>(<xsl:value of               select="seller_info/seller_rating"/>)
        </div>
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

I do have a CSS stylesheet but Ive even tried removing that but still doesnt work it just displays all the text in the XML with no formatting from the XSL stylesheet, sorry if I missing something obvious :-)

I have tried double checking the code, I have taken out the CSS stylesheet

Comment: To begin with, your stylesheet has several syntax errors such as mismatched start and end tags and missing quotes around attributes. Instead of a browser, try using a testing environment that provides useful error messages.

Comment: Oh really, I have copied this word for word from a Udemy course, thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Any current, supported browser, make sure the XML document is loaded over HTTP(S), the `xml-stylesheet` pi is not going to work if you load the XML from the file system, unless you start e.g. Chrome with reduced security settings.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanks I did that loaded it with reduced security I still cant see whats wrong with it lol, its just not wanting to work Ive even copied and pasted it from the course and nothing :-(

Comment: If you're just starting out and want to test/learn some XSLT, I suggest you use https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ to quickly try out your basic XSLT.

Comment: If you are using a course then ask your course instructor. But how is this question different from your previous? The main problem seems to understand how to set up a HTTP server to serve your XML so that the browser applies any XSLT linked with an `xml-stylesheet` pi. If you simply need any working XSLT stylesheet linked with `xml-stylesheet` see e.g. https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/exslt-functions-test.xml.

Comment: Knowing that you "tried everything" doesn't actually help us answer your question. It would be much more useful to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Although you say you "tried everything", I suspect that the only thing you tried was running this stylesheet in the browser, and you probably tried running it with the XML and XSLT in filestore rather than accessed over HTTP. I also suspect that you didn't read the diagnostic messages in the browser's developer console, which might have helped you.

I would suggest that when learning XSLT, you don't try running in the browser until you have gained a level of proficiency in the language. Ideally, start with an XML development environment such as Oxygen (you get what you pay for).

If this XSLT code is copied-and-pasted from published course notes then no-one has proof-read the course notes. Either that, or they are encouraging you to think by including deliberate errors in the examples. That's not actually a bad idea: if you can't spot the errors in this code, then you're not going to learn much by copying and pasting it.